# Do we need another controller when using ArduPilot?

Tags: programming

I'm a newbie on the all Arduino platform and I'm currently building a drone with Autopilot functionality. I've heard about ArduPilot and I'm wondering if that is all I need, in terms of controllers (I'm excluding the ESC, engines, and the rest). Can I simply program the ArduPilot, connect a Wireless interface to it and merrily be able to control it ?

Cheers,
r

Answer (score 1):

There are a few key points worth making before answering your question:

- **Ardupilot** has undergone a re-branding and is now known as **APM**; this change was made to reflect that the technology has grown beyond strictly using an Arduino environment. You can see this for yourself at [their website](http://ardupilot.com/).
- The term(s) Ardupilot/APM have been used somewhat interchangeably for both the hardware and software. This can be confusing so I'll refer to the hardware as an "APM Kit"

**Can I simply program the ArduPilot, connect a Wireless interface to it and merrily be able to control it ?**

Yes, [3DRobotics](http://store.3drobotics.com/t/parts/autopilots) offers APM Kits that are plug-and-play hardware packages with preloaded firmware. They (optionally) supply all of the components needed to operate a small unmanned hobby aircraft including:

- Power module
- Transmitter and receiver for the APM-to-Ground-Station link
- GPS module w/ compass

The user is generally expected to provide:

- Airframe
- Batteries
- Servos
- RC transmitter and receiver
- An additional voltage-regulator/BEC if using high-torque servos
- A computer (groundstation)

However, the unspoken question is:

**How easy is it to setup Ardupilot/APM to work safely and correctly?**

In truth, it takes considerable effort to put together a properly working system. The plug-and-play hardware saves you a great deal of trouble but tuning and operating an RC aircraft requires a different skillset. If you're experienced in RC, this *may* not be a problem.

From experience, you can expect to spend a number of weekends configuring and tuning APM (the software) even if you have a perfectly tuned RC aircraft.